# Creating a file that becomes executable chmod 777 gihook file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, ubuntu, githooks

I'm working in rails on UBUNTU

IM triggering an initializer that writes a githook file into the git directory, all good, file gets created code is good, but on the commit trigger I get

```
hint: The '.git/hooks/commit-msg' hook was ignored because it's not set as executable.
hint: You can disable this warning with `git config advice.ignoredHook false`.
```

The file is created with executable rights.... I think?

```
new_file = File.new(file, File::CREAT|File::TRUNC|File::RDWR, 777)
```

However, I think I'm doing something wrong or missing a permission step?

Secondly, how do I access the variables in the commit from the githook? is there good documentation somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in your Ruby code.  In general, Unix file modes are specified in octal, which is one of the last cases where people practically use octal in programming.  However, you've specified a decimal value here.

As a result, the octal mode you've specified is `1411`, which makes your file have no executable permissions for the user, no read permissions for group or other, and the sticky bit set, which is probably not what you wanted.

You can fix this by writing the mode as `0777`:

```
new_file = File.new(file, File::CREAT|File::TRUNC|File::RDWR, 0777)
```

Note also that it is in general a security problem to write files with mode 777, since any user on the system can modify them.  That means that any user who can access the directory in which this hook is written can modify it to execute arbitrary code whenever the hook is run (which, it looks like, is when `git commit` is run).  A more appropriate mode might be 755, which prevents parties other than the user from modifying it.

The documentation for the `commit-msg` hook is in the `githooks` manual page.  According to the documentation:

> It takes a single parameter, the name of the file that holds the proposed commit log message. Exiting with a non-zero status causes the command to abort.

Comment: Thank you for such a complete answer, I have altered it to 0755 instead of the fully open 0777 , I had tried 0777 but it had failed..... BECAUSE i stupidly changed the file name to a test file and forgot about this, so my changes were not getting executed regardless...

That will teach me to code after midnight.